# Django Translations won't show up

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I am attempting to setup translation using Django's built in translation system. I followed Marina Mele's excellent tutorial at:

http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones#inter-settings

I am using Django 1.8-1.

After following the tutorial, I have the following settings:

**settings.py**

```
import os
from .confidential import KEY
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = KEY

DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third party useful apps
    'crispy_forms',

    # my apps
    'plan_b_profile',
    'django_countries',
    'captcha',
)

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'


CONFIRMATION_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/confirm/'


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'younityb.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'younityb.wsgi.application'

# internationalization settings
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Montreal'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr-ca', _('French (Canada)')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Montreal'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_in_env","static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS =(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_in_pro'),
)



MEDIA_URL='/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_in_env","media_root")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', 'plan_b_profile.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^confirm/','plan_b_profile.views.confirm', name='confirm'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The .po and .mo files are being generated and translations are being shown in my admin but I do not see my translations on my home view. In my templates I put the appropriate {% trans %} fields and also put {% load i18n %} at the top of the template. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution! Be careful with the names of your folders in your locale folder (folder with translation files). Make sure that for the filename, hyphens are underscored as follows:

French-Canada : fr-ca but the filename is fr_ca

Comment: In my case `LANGUAGE_CODE` was set to `nb-no`, but the only folder name I got to work was `nb`